# Passing two values through CommandArgument and splitting it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the commandArgument property of the LinkButton ( Which is wrapped inside a repeater ) to pass two values -as one string- to a second repeater then I try to split them into two values, So I could use them as parameters in my ADO.NET Code (SqlCommand Parameters)....after testing my queries don't return any results but If I passed fixed values for the parameter or change the source of the parameter (just for test from a textbox or querystring or something) I get my results, so I think the problem is in splitting.

I Conduct some arugment values from the ArgumentCommand property of the LinkButton -which is wrapped inside a repeater:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton id="sort_lnkbtn" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>' 
         CommandArgument='<%#string.Format("{0}|{1}",Eval("arrange_by_id"),Eval("value"))%>' runat="server">
      </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Then I receive these values and cut them into two pieces of information:

```
        string sortByAndArrangeBy = (e.CommandArgument).ToString();
        char[] separator = { '|' };
        string[] sortByAndArrangeByArray = sortByAndArrangeBy.Split(separator);
```

Now the ado.net code uses this values as a

```
using (SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [name] FROM brands WHERE (name like @SearchString + '%' )", cn1))
                        {
                            cm1.Parameters.Add("@SearchString", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char);
                            cm1.Parameters["@SearchString"].Value = sortByAndArrangeByArray[1];

                            cn1.Open();
                            using (SqlDataReader dr1 = cm1.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                List_rpt.DataSource = dr1;
                                List_rpt.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what values do you actually get in sortByAndArrangeByArray? have you checked them?

Comment: yh, and I get the exactly values I expect! but they still won't be valuable as a parameter resource!
sortByAndArrangeByArray[0] returns a number from 1 to 3
and sortByAndArrangeByArray[1] returns a char which contains one of the alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

Wrap your item template for the repeater in a control. The control will have the same markup as your item template without the bindings:

Control Markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnSort" runat="server" Text="Sort" OnClick="LnkBtnSort_Clicked"/>
</div>
```

Control Code:

```
public class SomeControl
{
     public event EventHandler Click;

     public string ArrangeById 
     { 
         set { ViewState["byid"] = value; } 
         get { return ViewState["byid"].ToString(); } 
     }

     public string Value
     {
         set { ViewState["val"] = value; } 
         get { return ViewState["val"].ToString(); }
     }

     protected void LnkBtnSort_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if( Click != null )
         {
             this.Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
     }
}
```

So now in the repeater all you have to do is bind an instance of that control to the Container.DataItem:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <ctrl:SomeControl 
         ID="someControl" 
         runat="server" 
         OnClick="SomeControl_Clicked"
         ArrangeById='<%# Eval("arrange_by_id") %>'
         Value='<%# Eval("value") %>' /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

The page/control that has the repeater will have one simple method:

```
protected void SomeControl_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here cast the sender to the type of control you made:

    SomeControl ctrl = (SomeControl)sender;

    string byId = ctrl.ArrangeById;
    string val = ctrl.Value;
}
```

Note: this code may not be 100% correct but it illustrates the point. The flow is simple - the control binds its public properties to whatever you need to bind. When the link is clicked (inside your control) the control doesn't propagate this event to the page. Instead it fires its own event (Click) thus sending a signal to the page that an event occured. however by doing so, it changes the source of the event to itself instead of the actual link button. The page handles the event and everyone is happy.

This way you don't have to care what the CommandArgument is... If this comes up empty, it means that either your data source is empty... or something else happened in the code.

Comment: why did you use ViewState in the properties instead of some local variables ?

btw my example is already working but there is something with the splitting, any idea why it's not working ?

Comment: btw, what's exactly the function of the LnkBtnSort_Clicked Method ?

Comment: Marked as answer, since it at least a clean possible solution to my case in general! Thank you =)

Comment: I used the view state because that's the only way to persist the bound data between postbacks. You have to keep in mind that if you use just regular variables, when you click the link inside the control the entire ASP.NET life cycle happens. Load, Render, PreRender etc.. before the click event is handled. The regular variables will not persist in the life cycle unless you store them in the view state. Also keep in mind that the view state is actually stored in a hidden field inside the asp.net form and that's how it is persisted across postbacks.