# LinkButton passing multivalue possible clean solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I once asked for a way to let a linkbutton pass more than one value in the commandArgument and then I reached the approach where I pass a string of multiple values separated by any character and split it into it's original parts...that didn't work out I don't know what was wrong with the splitting!

Now I tried the only solution I got, which is created a user control of the LinkButton and add properties to accept any values nedeed!...could you please tell me what's wrong with my 2 approaches and which is better ?

The first question can be found here : [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379591/passing-two-values-through-commandargument-and-splitting-it)

and this is the code for the user control approach >>

MultivaluedLinkButton.ascx :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnSort" runat="server" Text="Sort" OnClick="LnkBtnSort_Clicked"/>
```

MultivaluedLinkButton.ascx.cs :

```
public partial class MultivaluedLinkButton : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler Click;
    private int _sortingType;
    private string _sortingFactor;
    private string _text;

 public int SortingType 
 { 
     set { _sortingType = value; } 
     get { return _sortingType; } 
 }

 public string SortingFactor
 {
     set { _sortingFactor = value; } 
     get { return _sortingFactor.ToString(); }
 }

 //public string Text
 //{
 //    set { _text = value; }
 //    get { return _text.ToString(); }
 //}

 protected void LnkBtnSort_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if( Click != null )
     {
         this.Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
 }

}
```

Finally, Here's the implementation of my control inside an aspx page:

```
    protected void MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MultivaluedLinkButton ctrl = (MultivaluedLinkButton)sender;

        using (SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(commandString2, cn1))
            {

                cm1.Parameters.Add("@arrange_by_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                cm1.Parameters["@arrange_by_id"].Value = ctrl.SortingType;
                cn1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr1 = cm1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    SortBy_rpt.DataSource = dr1;
                    SortBy_rpt.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The item template of the repeater in the implementation page :

```
   <ItemTemplate>
   <uc1:MultivaluedLinkButton ID="MultivaluedLinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked" SortingType='<%#Eval("arrange_by_id")%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i see is, you have an eventHandler in your usercontrol which you never really use.

Not 100% sure but, on the Page_Load of your parent page, you need to add MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked event to your handler.

```
MultivaluedLinkButton1.EventHandler_Click = new EventHandler(this.MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked);
MultivaluedLinkButton1.LnkBtnSort.Click = MultivaluedLinkButton1.EventHandler_Click;
```

Basically you are telling that when a user clicks on your linkbutton, MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked() on the parent page should be called.

You can remove OnClick="MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked"  from your UserControl properties on your parent page.

Comment: MultivaluedLinkButton1 is not accessible because it's inside a repeater, so it's ID in not unique, although MultivaluedLinkButton1_Clicked is accessible!
no idea if your answer is right, or how to access it in the page_load!